# Binding div to right border of another div

Tags: javascript, html, css

Please take a look at [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eugenymelamud/jzawoof0/4/). In html I have...

```
<div class='block1'>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text2</p>
  <p>text 3</p>
  <div class='block2'>block2</div>
  <div class='block3'>
    <p>block3</p>
    <div class='block2'>block4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

in CSS...

.block1 {
  color: red;
  width: 100px;
  border: 2px solid green;
  position: relative;
}

```
.block2 {
  color: blue;
  width: 70px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 110px;
}

.block3 {
  color: blue;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 35px;
  left: 120px;
}
```

As you can see divs are positioned with `left`. So to place a div I need to get width of it's "parent", add width of gap and then set `left` property.

Is the same (I mean placing a `div` 10px right from right border of it's "parent" div) can be done with CSS only without updating `left` with javascript each time the width of parent div is changed?

**PS.** Yes, I thought of using `float` in CSS, but as you can see I can have several divs at right border of "parent" div, and gaps between divs can be different.

Comment: I am sorry i didnt understand how you want to see your divs.

Comment: It looks like you are using `right` instead of `left`. Is that giving you the behavior you are looking for?

Comment: @csum I've updated the question. But it doesn't matter what to use left or right. I need to set property manualy each time in both cases

Comment: @varunaaruru, please take a look at jsfiddle. I want to see them exactly as they are there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `left: 100%;` and `margin-left` to whatever spacing you want away from the right edge of `.block1`:

```
.block1 {
  color: red;
  width: 100px;
  border: 2px solid green;
  position: relative;
}

.block2 {
  color: blue;
  width: 70px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 100%;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.block3 {
  color: blue;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 35px;
  left: 100%;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're looking for `left: 100%`.

Replace `right: -115px` and `right: -80px` with `left: 100%`. In doing so, you don't need to hardcode the width, and each element is positioned `100%` to the left. This will place each element at the right side of their positioned parent element:

```css
.block1 {
  color: red;
  width: 100px;
  border: 2px solid green;
  position: relative;
}
.block2 {
  color: blue;
  width: 70px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 100%;
}
.block3 {
  color: blue;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 35px;
  left: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class='block1'>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text2</p>
  <p>text 3</p>
  <div class='block2'>block2</div>
  <div class='block3'>
    <p>block3</p>
    <div class='block2'>block4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```